# How to add zoom IN/ZOOM out functionity into chart control

Tags: jquery, asp.net, charts, mschart, microsoft-chart-controls

I have created chart using microsoft chart control.

Below is the stuff.

```
 <asp:Chart ID="dntdata" runat="server" Height="130px" Width="134px" Visible="false">
            <Series>
                <asp:Series Name="Series1" ChartType="Doughnut" IsValueShownAsLabel="True" LabelForeColor="White" Font="Verdana,5pt">
                    <Points>
                    </Points>
                </asp:Series>

            </Series>
            <ChartAreas>
                <asp:ChartArea Name="ChartArea1" Area3DStyle-Enable3D="True">
                </asp:ChartArea>
            </ChartAreas>
        </asp:Chart>
```

I need to add - ZOOM IN/ZOOM OUT functionality into this chart image.
Please suggest me how i could achieve this ?

Share me some stuff it would be helpful.

if ANY ONE can achieve though JQUERY then also fine.

thank You

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, you could use the URL property of a single data-point (this property: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.datavisualization.charting.datapointcustomproperties.url(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.datavisualization.charting.datapointcustomproperties.url%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

With this, you can define a target URL which is called when a user clicks on the data point, then you can render a detailed chart for the selected point.

Hope that helps,
Chris